# ASP.NET VB convert number to invariant

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On a multi-lingual site, an AJAX call hits a function that returns either a number or a text message. The in-page javascript then does an IsNumeric check on the data and either alerts the message or adds the value to an existing number.

Problem is that if the language selected is not EN then the number comes back as 15,0000 instead of 15.0000, so the javascript gives NaN for the result of the addition.

Trying to convert the database output to invariant culture fails and I can't work out why:-

```
Using DBConn As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString.DBConnStr.ToString())

Using Comm As New SqlCommand("ValidateVoucher", DBConn)
    Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    With Comm.Parameters
        'Input Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@VoucherCode", voucherCode)
        .AddWithValue("@MemberID", CType(memberID, Integer))
        .AddWithValue("@WeekDetailsID", CType(weekID, Integer))
        .AddWithValue("@LanguageID", CType(languageID, Integer))

        'Output Parameters
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@ReturnMessage", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 500)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@CurrencyCode", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 3)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        .Add(New SqlParameter("@VoucherValue", Data.SqlDbType.Money)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    End With

    Try
        DBConn.Open()
        Comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If Comm.Parameters("@ReturnMessage").Value = "OK" Then
            responseString = Comm.Parameters("@VoucherValue").Value.ToString()
            responseString = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0.0000}", responseString)
        Else
            responseString = Comm.Parameters("@ReturnMessage").Value
        End If

    Catch

    End Try
End Using
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `String.Format` with a parameter which is already a string - the result of `Comm.Parameters("@VoucherValue").Value.ToString()`. That `ToString` call doesn't specify a string format, so the default format is used with the current culture.

Also, your format string is wrong. It should start with the parameter index, followed by a colon, and then the format specifier for the parameter.

Try passing the value directly to the `String.Format` method:

```
responseString = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:###0.0000}", _
   Comm.Parameters("@VoucherValue").Value)
```